# Он представил их в своем доме(,) играющими в прятки

Tags: пунктуация

Подскажите, пожалуйста, нужна ли запятая.
Он представил их в своем доме(,) играющими в прятки.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Он представил их в своем доме играющими в прятки.*

Он (что сделал?) представил  играющими в прятки . Это не причастный оборот, сочетание причастия с существительным очень тесно связано со сказуемым, поэтому не отделяется запятой.

Причастный оборот был бы в таком разговорном варианте: В своём доме он представил их,  играющих в прятки.